# How to open my app even if the screen is locked?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to display an alarm screen whenever the alarm hits. I have a special widget for that (Inside of my main application). I want to open that app inorder to show the widget. Now, how can I open it even if there is a screen lock?

I tried using external_app_launcher to launch the app but it doesnt open it in the lockscreen

I have added those two tags to my main activity:

```
        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity" 
            android:exported="true" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
            android:showWhenLocked="true" 
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
        >
```

Comment: you need wack lock permission for this

Comment: But I dont want the user's device to be always waken up

Comment: You might want to use https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock package.